# switching between fragments on click of recycler view item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing a screen for android tablet, there is one recycler view on the right with a list of options to select and a frame layout on the right side.I need to load different fragments in the frame layout based on the item clicked from the recycler view. How can i do this ? Any help or sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to make sure the event gets forwarded to your containing activity. Then your activity can do a FragmentTransaction to load the fragment into the FrameLayout.

Comment: you mean to say that the onclick event should get forwarded to the activity ?

Comment: Yea, ideally it would. There are a lot of ways to do this, using an interface is the most common one and I would recommend that.

Comment: yea, but how do i switch between the fragments ? any sample code ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: @BAbhilash share some source code

Comment: @TimKranen Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Declare an interface in the fragment with list

Step 2: implement the interface in the containing activity

Step 3: Call the interface method when an item is selected in the list

step 4: in the Callback method(in the activity) you can add the corresponding fragment